# My Ubuntu doesn't install things

Tags: software-installation, software-center, steam

I don't understand what is actually happening, but I tried installing Steam, Opera and both times was unsuccesful. I think the program "Ubuntu software" is not working properly. For instance, if I type "Opera" on Ubuntu Software, an option to download and install the browser should show up, but it doesn't.

When I download the programs and try to install them (both opera and steam) via Ubuntu software, the following message appears on the Ubuntu Software window: "This software comes from a third party and could contain non-free components". And although I press the button "Install", nothing happens.

I was able, however, to install VIM, Synaptic, GNU.

Have anyone ever had a problem like this? Can anyone imagine how to solve this?

Comment: Opera and Steam are not in Ubuntu Software. If you succeeded in downloading and installing them from the web, then you should be able, for example, to open up the Dash and type "opera", and a launcher should appear.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, guys. I'll try it tomorrow (2am here), and I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be a dependency problem.

First, open the terminal and **cd** into the directory where you downloaded your .deb packages.

```
cd ~/path/to/your/files
```

Then try to install a program.deb with dpkg program

```
sudo dpkg -i program.deb
```

If this command fails, it will inform you that the program you're trying to install depends on some other packages. To fix dependency issues, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This command will install all the required packages, automatically. After this command finishes you can

```
sudo dpkg -i program.deb
```

To continue installing your desired programs.

Comment: you sir, are an angel.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and make sure you installed all system updates. [bug #1573206](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573408)
Then try again via Ubuntu Software